# Add a span element to my button in order to display spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I have this button in a table:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='buitton1" ?>'>Edit</button></td>
```

I would like to add the following span element in a script with click event, in order to display a loading spinner from bootstrap:

```
<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

But I don't know what to use in the script. I tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
```

Comment: use `innerHTML`

Comment: Please include all the relevant code, specifically the click event that surrounds your insert code.   See [mcve].

Comment: Are you using [tag:jquery] or want a jquery solution?  You don't currently have jquery.